# How to make ConstraintLayout work properly for RTL?

Tags: android, right-to-left, android-constraintlayout

Does somebody know why when switching to rtl, ConstraintLayout centers all elements?

`android:supportsRtl="true"` in manifest is set.

`BookShelfActivity.java` contains only standard onCreate override:

```
public class BookShelfActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_shelf);
    }
}
```

Here is the activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_book_shelf"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hekayh.ereader.BookShelfActivity"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="AnotherTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textView5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="277dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_book_shelf"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_book_shelf"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I believe its a bug.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely a bug, but may be somebody tried to fix it using source code of Constraint Layout.. *-*

Comment: Found that latest com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha6 seems to be free from this.

Comment: I upvoted just because its a problem about the crappy library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a bug i reported before and it get solved in alpha 6
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218979

but there is another bug about rtl i need to support it by a comment
here
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220103

**Updates:**
developer mentioned that second RTL bug solved:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222556